# Error Installing MPI for Rust: failed to run custom build command

Tags: rust, mpi

Please assist, i am trying to install MPI for Rust and i am getting the follwing error :

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `mpi-sys v0.2.0 (https://github.com/rsmpi/rsmpi#055d5036)`                                 
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully..
```

added the `[dependency]` as follows: `mpi = { git = "https://github.com/rsmpi/rsmpi" }` .I tried following the documentation in github adding  the `[dependency]` as follows : `mpi = "0.5"` but I received the following error :

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `libffi-sys v0.6.3`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully:
```

Comment: Please provide more context: What command did you run to get the output (I assume `cargo build`)? Why have you added the dependency the way you did and not as the instructions on the GitHub page say?

Comment: Edited my question. see above.

Comment: Please add more context. There should be some message describing the failing command.